# Proving ${\frac {35{x}^{2}+7x(y+z)+23yz}{35(x^2+y^2+z^2)+37(xy+yz+zx)}}\leqslant \sqrt {{\frac {{x}^{2}+yz}{6\,{y}^{2} +6\,yz+6\,{z}^{2}}}}$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, sum-of-squares-method, buffalo-way

For $x,y,z \geqslant 0.$ Proving$:$

$${\dfrac {35{x}^{2}+7x(y+z)+23yz}{35(x^2+y^2+z^2)+37(xy+yz+zx)}}\leqslant \sqrt {{\dfrac {{x}^{2}+yz}{6{y}^{2}
+6yz+6{z}^{2}}}}\quad \quad(\text{tthnew})$$

My proof is using Buffalo Way$.$ By assuming $y\geqslant z,$ we only need to consider three cases:

$+)$ $x\geqslant y\geqslant z,$ let $x=z+u+v,y=z+u$ with helping by computer to simplify expression and we are done.

$+)$ $y\geqslant x \geqslant z,$ let $y=z+u+v,x=z+u$ and done after simplify..

$+)$ $y\geqslant z \geqslant x,$ we can prove by the similar way too!

And we are done! But it's not the nice proof. So any one have other$?$

**Note.** This inequality is a proof for Vo Quoc Ba Can's inequality$:$

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+bc}{b^2+bc+c^2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{b^2+ca}{c^2+ca+a^2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{c^2+ab}{a^2+ab+b^2}} \geqslant \sqrt{6}\,\,(\text{1})$$

$(\text{1})$ is inspired from the familiar Vasile Cîrtoaje's inequality$:$

$$\dfrac{a^2+bc}{b^2+bc+c^2}+\dfrac{b^2+ca}{c^2+ca+a^2}+\dfrac{c^2+ab}{a^2+ab+b^2} \geqslant 2$$

Also we have the following inequality by Crazy_LittleBoy (AoPS)

$${\frac { \left( {\frac {49\,\sqrt {2}}{12}}-{\frac {17}{3}} \right) x
\left( y+z \right) +{x}^{2}+ \left( \frac73-\frac76\sqrt {2} \right) yz}{{x
}^{2}+{y}^{2}+{z}^{2}+ \left( 7\,\sqrt {2}-9 \right) \left( xy+xz+yz
\right) }}\leq \sqrt {{\frac {{x}^{2}+yz}{6\,{y}^{2}+6\,yz+6\,{z}^{2}
}}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

[image: Maple 17]

By Maple we have $$\sqrt{\frac{6(a^2+bc)}{b^2+bc+c^2}}\ge \frac{6a^2+4bc+ab+ac}{a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca}$$

Note that $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{6a^2+4bc+ab+ac}{a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca}=6$$
then we are done

Comment: But I need solution for my inequality, is not the original.